# Send backend data (hidden and non editable) to Codeigniter controller on submit Form

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I've send some `$data` from controller to view. the view is contain a `<form>`. How to send this `$data` to controller on submit form to controller (sub function in same controller)?

Ex:

Controller

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {
  function index(){
    $this->load->view('login', $data['data']);
  }

  function get_data(){
    $input_value = $this->input->post('bla');

    /*--- here is my point of question ---
    I wan't to call $data here and $data shuold same as $data at index()
    */
    $this->model_file->insert_data_and_input_value_to_DB($data, $input_value);
  } 

}
```

View

```
// $data is ready 

echo form_open('register/get_data');
echo '<input name='bla' />';
echo '<input type='submit' value='SEND input value and $data TOO'/>
echo form_close();
```

Comment: How do you create `$data` array in index method?

Comment: $data is come from Google Auth API client by Login Google. i've set some google response data (email, Google+ id) to $data.

Comment: You have to persist those data either in session either in database or file. That is for case we are not talking about same request.

Comment: yes, it's possible to do that with database or file. but i wan't to reduce process on my server. In session I think $data have option to editable.

Comment: I typically call from controller a model with like $this->model->add(); and do all action there / move ur logic to model

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft I don't understand it. Can you explain it with some codes?

Comment: Show ur full code, data is not assigned anywhere

Comment: As simple as: `$data` doesn't exist in `get_data()` method unless you call it from some source like session for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. One of them is below

```
Simply change your view like this

    $data = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'bag', 'c' => 'cat' );
    $data = base64_encode(serialize($data));

    echo '<form action="register/get_data" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="bla" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="'.$data.'">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="SEND"/>';
    echo '</form>';
```

Change you Controller like this

```
    class Register extends CI_Controller {
         function index(){
            $this->load->view('login', $data['data']);
         }

         function get_data(){
                $input_value = $this->input->post('bla');

                if ($_POST) {
                    print_r(unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['data'])));
                }
               $this->model_file->insert_data_and_input_value_to_DB($data, $input_value);
        } 

    }
```

Hope this will help.